# Java applet is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet

I got this message when I tried to open a Java applet page in IE.

[image]

alert message for running applet

I set internet option settings, and checked Java(JRE), and script, HTML applet code, file existing on directory.

But it is not working. Something strange is.  In some desktops, it's working.

I compared setting options(window control > JAVA, browser settings), but it looks the same.

What is the problem and solution?

Comment: Maybe JRE (Java Runtime Environment) might not have been set-up properly on your machine.  Try links on this test page - https://www.w3.org/People/mimasa/test/object/java/ - Do those links show up the details as expected, if not, definitely some JRE related issue is there.  Uninstall Java and install JRE again.

Comment: Also, Internet Explorer is an out-dated browser.  Try using Edge, Chrome, & Firefox, etc. actively managed browsers.

Comment: Java applets are deprecated technology.  They were officially deprecated by Oracle in Java 9, and well know to be problematic for a long time before that.  The only browser that still supports Applets is Internet Explorer, and IE has been EOL since June 14, 2022.  You really should stop using applets ...

Comment: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.html explains how to enable Java in IE.